# C#, Atata Framework: Unable to use .Hover() Control method after updated Selenium.WebDriver to v 4.3

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, atata

Element example:

```
[FindByCss("input[formcontrolname='name']")]
public TextInput<TOwner> NameInput { get; private set; }
```

Code that throws the error:

```
editProjectPage.NameInput.Hover();
```

After updating Selenium.WebDriver to v 4.3 on the test run returns such an error:

[image: Tough life of AT]

Error message:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions.MoveToElement(OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement, Int32, Int32, OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.MoveToElementOffsetOrigin)'.'

So far worked around with such a spike method:

```
public static void EmulateHover<TOwner>(IControl<TOwner> element) where TOwner : PageObject<TOwner>
{
    var sourceElement = element.Scope;
    var actions = new Actions(element.Context.Driver);
    actions.ScrollToElement(sourceElement);
    actions.MoveToElement(sourceElement);
    actions.Build().Perform();
}
```

But in implementation, it looks... like a spike ;) Any suggestion if it will be fixed or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Actions.MoveToElement(IWebElement, Int32, Int32, MoveToElementOffsetOrigin)` method was removed in WevDriver v4.3. Current Atata v2.0.1 uses that method to hover elements.

Let me upgrade Atata to WevDriver v4.3, solve that error by using another `MoveToElement` method overload, and publish Atata v2.1.0. I'll update this answer after release.

**Update**

Atata v2.1.0 is released. Please update and verify whether `Hover()` method works. It should be fine now.

Comment: please notice that DoubleClickAndGo() Method was impacted in the same way.

Comment: @OleksandrMakar, have you tried newest Atata v2.1.0? Yes, both `Hover` and `DoubleClick` use the same method under the hood. But now they both work fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answear. I checked everything - DoubleClickAndGo() and Hover() methods now, with Atata v2.1.0, work perfectly! Ty, Yevgeniy Shunevych!